# problem in upgrading 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

when i try this command for upgrade

```
~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

i get this results and cannot get my system upgraded.. any reason behind this??
 i could show the full result as i have less reputations

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,258 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,258 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease               
Get:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  

Fetched 125 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Why are you using `-d`? 18.04 is not a development release.

Comment: if not i am being notified no release found

Comment: That's because it's not ready yet. There are problems with the update process.https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html  You shouldn't be so impatient.

Comment: i already updated my system to 18.04 and it works soundly!! i guess i had problems in my previous ubuntu 16.04

Comment: facing similiar issue.... what can be the problem?